# Is there a way to have structmap inject an array of all implementations of an interface?

Tags: structuremap

Example

```
MyConstruction(IEnumberable<IMyInterface> myInterfaces)
{
}
```

where I have a couple of classes that implement IMyInterface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to declare them explicitly. Take advantage of the scanning feature:

```
Scan(x =>
{
    x.TheCallingAssembly(); // or specify additional assemblies to scan

    x.AddAllTypesOf<IMyInterface>();
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I use scan now, I was just missing the AddAllTypes call. Haven't seen that one before.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a blog post describing this issue.  It isn't exactly what I was looking for because I would rather not have to explicitly list the implementations.

http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/09/03/building-arrays-in-structuremap-2-5.aspx